# ActivityCompat2 not showing animation - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm testing out the ActivityCompat2 library to see if I can get ActivityOptions animations working pre api 16. I can get the new activity to start with ActivityCompat2 but no animations are shown. Any ideas? My code in MainActivity looks like

```
listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailActivity.class);
        ActivityOptionsCompat2 opts = ActivityOptionsCompat2.makeScaleUpAnimation(
                                    view,0, 0,view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        ActivityCompat2.startActivity(MainActivity.this, intent, opts.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Animations are enabled on the device.
Settings -> Display -> Animation -> All animations